# Parola per indicare la persona che è alla porta di una scuola

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Qual è il vocabolo che si usa di solito per indicare la persona che è alla porta di una scuola o di un liceo? Ho pensato a "portinaio", nella accezione del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/portinaio/)

> Con accezione più generica, custode di una porta;

ma non sono sicura che questo sia il termine veramente usato. In questa entrata del Treccani, ho visto che appare anche la parola "portiere"

> in tale accezione, il termine, usato solo al masch., talora alternandosi con *portiere*,

non so se sia questo il termine adatto. C'è poi anche il termine "custode" che però mi sembra più generico. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi facendo magari qualche esempio di uso nel caso che la persona addetta a tale mansione sia una donna? Dico questo dopo aver letto "il termine, usato solo al masch." nel Treccani, che ancora mi confonde di più (non posso dire "la portinaia"?).

Comment: Per favore, la persona che ha dato il voto negativo potrebbe spiegare perché? Non sono italiana, e per me non è sempre tanto facile trovare il vocabolario adatto per esprimere un certo concetto. Se poi non è lecito fare la domanda qui... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nella pratica quotidiana (almeno a Roma) il termine abituale è indubbiamente **[bidello](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bidello/)** (e **bidella**). Tecnicamente è detto *collaboratore scolastico*, che fa parte del personale ATA (cf. https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personale_amministrativo,_tecnico_e_ausiliario), ma il termine “bidello” è quello usato da genitori, bimbi e insegnanti.

(Il “portinaio” solo maschile della Treccani si riferisce al guardiano delle porte delle città etc.; quello delle case può benissimo essere una “portinaia” donna. Anche nel senso delle case d'abitazione si usa anche “portiere” e “portiera”.)

Comment: Tecnicamente il bidello fa parte del personale ATA https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personale_amministrativo,_tecnico_e_ausiliario

Comment: Grazie @abarisone, aggiungo alla risposta.

Answer (score 0):

Dipende dal ruolo che svolge.
"Custode" se apre/chiude la scuola, regola gli accessi e ha un appartamento nello stesso edificio.
"Portinaio" se apre/chiude la scuola e regola gli accessi ma non vive nello stesso edificio.

"Bidello" (o "collaboratore scolastico" se si vuole essere politicamente corretti): non è un "custode" o un "portinaio" ma colui che pulisce la scuola, controlla i corridoi, porta le circolari in classe etc.

Comment: La persona che è alla porta di una scuola, cioè che controlla gli accessi alla scuola, nel mio paese (può darsi che in Italia sia un po' diverso) ha di solito altre mansioni come aprire e chiudere la scuola, fare fotocopie, portare le circolari in classe... (ma non quella della pulizia).

Comment: @Charo. Per questo il termine più appropriato, o perlomeno usato, è bidello.